# Empty space on the feed page

Tags: bug, android-app

Feed page contains to much empty space:

> [image: feed]

Existing items in the feed could have more suitable width.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: Nexus 10
- OS Version: 5.1.1 (2640980)